# Given N objects in my 3d world, how to set camera zoom to have all framed?

Tags: unity, algorithm, camera

I have N objects and I've done a routine to get the overall objects :

```
min_x, max_x
min_y, max_y
min_z, max_z
```

and, i have an

```
 Vector3 avarage_position
```

that is the avarage Vector3 position of all my objects in my 3d world.

Then I have a camera.

I set my camera to

```
LookAt(avarage_position)
```

So the camera look that point.

**Next step, that is my question is:  how to set Zoom (Y position of my camera) to frame all my objects having the min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, min_z,max_z  positions ?**

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015697/how-to-keep-2-objects-in-view-at-all-time-by-scaling-the-field-of-view-or-zy